# Deploying to Heroku with environment variables in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, rubymine

I've recently updated our Gemfile as `pry-byebug` and `bye-bug` were causing Rubymine to crash for some of my colleagues. Since there are some of us that use other editors I've added an environment variable to our Gemfile:

```
if ENV["USE_DEBUGGER"]
  gem "pry-byebug"
  gem "byebug"
end
```

This worked fine in our local machines but deploying to Heroku causes the following error: [gist](https://gist.github.com/gbonfant/3e8d85f6b44689041280)

I've tried running `bundle install` and committing a new `Gemfile.lock` but that changes nothing. Getting rid of the control flow declaration or simply removing the gems fixes the issue.It's worth nothing that in that same commit I bumped the required ruby version to 2.2.0

Is there any way to use conditional statements in the `Gemfile` without blowing Heroku up?

Comment: Almost immediately after posting this question I've just realised why this is happening: The env variable is defined in my local repo, which causes Gemfile.lock to include both gems, however since the variable is not defined in Heroku the gems are not installed by bundle but are still required by Gemfile.lock, causing all kind of issues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so after juggling with RubyMine I realised the problem occurs when `require`ing pry and any other related debugging gems. I managed to fix this by updating my Gemfile to the following:

```
  if ENV["USE_DEBUGGER"]
    gem "pry-byebug"
    gem "byebug"
  else
    gem "pry-byebug", require: false
    gem "byebug", require: false
  end
```

I hope this helps anybody facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the conditional in a group and try to `BUNDLE_WITHOUT` on deployment. [ref](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/partygrin/wiki/Using_Bundler_Groups_on_Heroku/history)

```
group :byebug do
  if ENV["USE_DEBUGGER"]
    gem "pry-byebug"
    gem "byebug"
  end
end
```

`heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="byebug"`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention both gems are in the `development` group, and as you can see in the gist I'm already running BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test" – So in theory these gems shouldn't be installed but somehow I still get the conflict.

Comment: Ok, sorry I missed that. Yeah my next guess was the Gemfile.lock. Have you been able to resolve the deployment issue?